# cloneStyleFrom shows ArrayIndexOutOfBound error while coping cellStyle using java poi, how to fix this issue

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, worksheet

I am trying to copy an excel workbook to another excel workbook(some cell values needs some calculations as per)
I need to copy the CellStyles as well, as there are Data and Amount fields with styling.
Im using the below lines of code :

CellStyle cellStyle = wb_out.createCellStyle();

cellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(cell_in.getCellStyle());

Cell cell_out = row_out.createCell(cellIndex);

cell_out.setCellValue(value);

cell_out.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

For large files,
The  **cloneStyleFrom** throws ArrayIndexOutofBound error,
How do we fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: In general, it is a good idea to reuse styles as Microsoft products will not properly handle cell styles if you add too many to a file.

Comment: Yes this is the exact issue, I tried to reuse the styles, it worked, i have put the code snippet below.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there's a limit to number of Styles that one can create,
and if the excel sheet is a large file, the limit crosses and the error 'ArrayIndexOutofBound' is thrown.This is called **Style explosion**.
To escape this scenario, you have to create separate cell styles and use it wherever is required
This is what I tried and it worked.

I created a cell style for the Date format and Currency format, and applied those wherever required.

> CellStyle cellStyleDate = wb_out.createCellStyle();
> short dateFormat = wb_out.createDataFormat().getFormat("d-mmm");
> cellStyleDate.setDataFormat(dateFormat);
>
> CellStyle cellStyleCurrency = wb_out.createCellStyle();
> short currencyFormat = wb_out.createDataFormat().getFormat("#,##0.0");
> cellStyleCurrency.setDataFormat(currencyFormat);

Likewise one can create a cell style and add different specific format or properties to it and use it in the workbook,
like this :

> cell_out.setCellStyle(cellStyleDate);